# Generating Safe Update Statements for SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I may be missing something here, but I've searched for hours and I'm either not finding what I need, or I'm not searching on the correct terms.  Never-the-less, this is what I'm trying to do.

I'm currently exploring migrating from EF to plain-old ADO.  I'm happy that whilst there is a development hit in doing so all current testing points to ADO still being many times faster than EF (which given EF is built on ADO makes sense).

Where I am a little stumped, is generating an update statement for a table row, and an efficient one.  Any update statement may change values in 1 or 10 fields, but it's clearly more efficient to only post the data that needs changing.

My question is, what is the best way to generate the update statement to as to remain protected from SQL injection?

For instance, one column value update would be

```
update Table1 set Column2 = 'somevalue' WHERE Column1 = @id;
```

Where two columns would be

```
update Table1 set Column2 = 'somevalue', Column 3 = 'some other value' WHERE Column1 = @id;
```

Does anyone have any best practises on how they handle this please?

**Additional Information:**

I've had this down-voted, but quite honestly I think that is because I haven't made myself clear in what I want.

Let me start be confirming that I understand I have options of straight-forward SQL commands (which I am fairly competent on) or placing the said command within a Stored Procedure and calling either from ADO.  I also fully understand the importance of using parameters in any SQL statement where user input is placed.

Imagine the following table:

```
DECLARE @example TABLE
(
Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Description VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL
);
-- Indexes omitted for simplicity
```

Now imagine I have an API, allowing users to update a row in this table.  The user can update either Name, Description OR both columns, simply by passing the Id.  The call is completely disconnected from any "result sets" and therefore I must issue an UPDATE command to the database manually (or through a Stored Procedure).

To keep data transmission to a minimum (therefore helping to maximise performance), I want to cater for the following scenarios:

- User updates just Name

  ```
  UPDATE @example SET [Name] = @name WHERE [Id] = @id;
  ```
- User updates just Description

  ```
  UPDATE @example SET [Description] = @description WHERE [Id] = @id;
  ```
- User updates both

  ```
  UPDATE @example SET [Name] = @name, [Description] = @description WHERE [Id] = @id;
  ```

After all, with each call, I don't know what the caller wishes to update.

In reality, tables can have many, many columns, and it in completely ridiculous to create the relevant SQL statements for every possible combination - let alone the ludicrous effort it would require to keep updated.

What I'm looking for (as I seem to be missing in searches) is how to generate a safe SQL statement that caters for each option based on what the user supplies AND uses parameters AND generates the smallest query possible - needed because we cannot update a column value if the user did not pass a value for it.

I hope this helps to clarify the requirement better.

Comment: You can use variables in your `set` clause just the same as in your `where` clause.

Comment: Create a stored procedure with the required input parameters.

Comment: thank you both for your comments, I fear I've not worded my question right (which I fear is half my problem).  Whether I use a sql statement or stored procedure is almost neither here or there (at the moment), what I'm trying to ask is how to safely use either whilst catering for a dynamic number of column updates. So put another way, how to generate a dynamic sql statement that uses sql parameters or how to write a stored procedure that caters for one, three or x column values being changed.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Parameterize ALL values in ALL cases. This will ensure you avoid SQL injection attacks. As far as patterns for tracking which fields have changed and thus need updating, that is a larger exercise with many examples available on the interwebs for your reading enjoyment.

```
update Table1
set Column2 = @Column2,
  Column3 = @Column3
where Column1 = @Column1
```

Comment: Rob, thank you for your answer.  I understand the importance of parameterising all values, and there is my problem.  I want to use parameters, but until the user updates the "entity", I don't know if they will change one, or ten column values and I'm trying to work out how to generate a dynamic sql statement (or stored procedure) that most efficiently updates only the columns whose values are being altered each time - which could be any combination of columns.  Does that make sense?